# Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm starting with TypeScript and I'm having the following problem:

I have a method that updates a record in the database, defined as follows:

```
class Category {
  update (data: ICategory & { id: string }): Promise<ICategory & { id: string }> {
    // Do Stuff
  }
}

interface ICategory {
  id?: string
  name: string,
  icon: string,
  iconColor: string
}
```

Note that the id field is optional in the interface, and the method required the id to be a string, and here lies the problem: when I try to call this method with the said interface, I get the following error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'ICategory' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ICategory & { id: string; }'.
  Type 'ICategory' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; }'.
    Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Even if I check that `typeof obj.id === 'string'` I continue to have the same error.

How can I solve this problem? As I said, I'm starting with TypeScript now, so any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling this method? What is the code that the error coming from?

Comment: @VLAZ I'm calling as follows: `category.update(this.form)`, and the form object is the following: `form: <ICategory>{ id: undefined, name: '', icon: '' iconColor: '' }`

Comment: Then I fail to see the problem. `id` is *not* a string. That's exactly what the method wants to prevent.

Comment: @VLAZ, sorry, my mistake, actually when I call the function, all the fields are filled. For example: `icon: "adb", iconColor: "#00a3a3", id: "CtmJOIi3ZbvF3cyeTxWt", name: "test"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) for that:

```js
interface FuncData {
    id: string;
}

function test(args: FuncData) { }

interface PartialData {
    id?: string;
}

const data: PartialData = { id: 'test' };

function funcDataGuard(data: PartialData): data is FuncData {
    return data.id != null;
}

if (funcDataGuard(data)) {
    test(data);
}
```